# Large File Size Upload - Using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, .htaccess, file-upload

I'm trying to upload a large file but the problem is I'm getting error and the file won't upload. I don't have any idea what is the problem with my code. But some small file size is uploading but the large file size won't upload. Please help me out with this problem.

**NOTE:** The file that I want to upload is 117 MB
**NOTE:** The uploading function is working if the size is small

Here's my code

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" id="user_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">
      <tr id="row1">
        <td width="48%" valign="bottom"><input type="text" id="text_video_title[]" name="text_video_title[]" placeholder="Enter your Name" class="form-control name_list" /></td>
        <td width="48%" valign="bottom"><input type="file" id="text_video[]" name="text_video[]" placeholder="Enter your Name" class="form-control name_list" /></td>
        <td valign="bottom"><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">Add More</button></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" name="action" id="action" class="btn btn-success" value="Add" />

    <!-- Progress bar -->
    <div class="progress">
      <div class="progress-bar"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- Display upload status -->
    <div id="uploadStatus"></div>
</form>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).on('submit', '#user_form', function(event){
event.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
      xhr: function() {
          var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
          xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt) {
              if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                  var percentComplete = ((evt.loaded / evt.total) * 100);
                  $(".progress-bar").width(percentComplete + '%');
                  $(".progress-bar").html(percentComplete.toFixed(0)+'%');

                  var percentComplete1 = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                  percentComplete1 = parseInt(percentComplete1 * 100);
                  // console.log(percentComplete1 + "test");
                  if(percentComplete1 == "100") 
                  {
                      $('#user_form')[0].reset();
                      alert(data);
                      $('#userModal').modal('hide');
                      dataTable.ajax.reload();
                  }
              }
          }, false);
          return xhr;
      },
      url:"insert.php",
      method:'POST',
      data:new FormData(this),
      contentType:false,
      processData:false,
      beforeSend: function(){
        $(".progress-bar").width('0%');
      },
      error:function(){
        alert("ERROR");
      },
      success:function(data)
      {
        alert(data);
        $('#user_form')[0].reset();
        $('#userModal').modal('hide');
        dataTable.ajax.reload();
      }
    });
   });
```

**PHP**

```
$number = count($_POST["text_video_title"]);
if($number >= 1)
  {
    for($i=0; $i<$number; $i++)
    {
      if(trim($_POST["text_video_title"][$i] != ''))
      {
          $extension = explode('.', $_FILES['text_video']['name'][$i]);
          $new_name = rand() . '.' . $extension[1];
          $destination = './video/' . $new_name;
          move_uploaded_file($_FILES['text_video']['tmp_name'][$i], $destination);

          $statement = $connection->prepare("
           INSERT INTO live_demo_videos (title, video, news_id) 
           VALUES (:text_video_title, :text_video, :text_id)
          ");
          $result = $statement->execute(
           array(
            ':text_video_title' => $_POST["text_video_title"][$i],
            ':text_video' => $new_name,
            ':text_id' => $id
           )
          );
      }
    }
  }
  if(!empty($result))
  {
   echo 'Data Inserted';
  }
```

**HTACCESS**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

ErrorDocument 400 /error_pages/400.php
ErrorDocument 401 /error_pages/401.php
ErrorDocument 403 /error_pages/403.php
ErrorDocument 404 /error_pages/404.php
ErrorDocument 410 /error_pages/410.php
ErrorDocument 500 /error_pages/500.php

#Serve .htc files correctly, for IE fixes
AddType text/x-component .htc

php_value upload_max_filesize 300M
php_value post_max_size 301M
php_value max_execution_time 20000
php_value max_input_time 20000
```

I don't know if my javascript code is the problem or PHP, please help me out with this problem. :( I don't know what to do. Thank you so much

Comment: *"I don't know if my javascript code is the problem or PHP"* - Have you tried it without the JS and/or the `.htaccess`? What does error reporting or logs show?

Comment: @Dave Check the error logs. You can find the exact reason behind this incident.

Comment: @invalidbot Hi Sir, I'm newbie about PHP, where can I find the error logs?